# What would you guys order this? Answer an incoming call, responding to an important question from a co-worker, or responding to an important email?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

How would you prioritize this? Answer an incoming call, responding to an important question from a co-worker, or responding to an important email?

Comment: Only you can prioritize the business importance in your environment.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no way for us to answer this. It really depends on your work priorities which would be assigned by you Boss. The one that comes first is whatever is more important to your boss.

Comment: If you can't take 10 seconds to hear who's calling and tell them you'll call them back, everything's clearly on fire.

Answer (score 2):

> How would you prioritize this?

I would **go to my boss and ask him/her to establish such priority**.

In case you are the manager, or are in managerial or decision-making position, then it will be *up to your judgment* to determine the priority.

I suggest you take into consideration the pros and cons of each thing to be done, so you can weight them and sort your tasks the way it's best for *"you"* (that is, what's best for you and the project).